# List comprehension: Returning two (or more) items for each item

Tags: python, list-comprehension

**Is it possible to return 2 (or more) items for each item in a list comprehension?**

What I want (example):

```
[f(x), g(x) for x in range(n)]
```

should return `[f(0), g(0), f(1), g(1), ..., f(n-1), g(n-1)]`

So, something to replace this block of code:

```
result = list()
for x in range(n):
    result.add(f(x))
    result.add(g(x))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? There might be a better way of achieving your end goal without trying to do it this way.

Comment: Mainly because I like functional programming.
I want to map a list of coordinates to a tuple of screen coordinates to use with pyglet.graphics.draw function.

Comment: Screen coordinates? As in XY-coordinates? Why do you want to split them up?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> f = lambda x: x + 2
>>> g = lambda x: x ** 2
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((f(x), g(x)) for x in range(3)))
[2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 4]
```

Timings:

```
from timeit import timeit

f = lambda x: x + 2
g = lambda x: x ** 2

def fg(x):
    yield f(x)
    yield g(x)

print timeit(stmt='list(chain.from_iterable((f(x), g(x)) for x in range(3)))',
             setup='gc.enable(); from itertools import chain; f = lambda x: x + 2; g = lambda x: x ** 2')

print timeit(stmt='list(chain.from_iterable(fg(x) for x in range(3)))',
             setup='gc.enable(); from itertools import chain; from __main__ import fg; f = lambda x: x + 2; g = lambda x: x ** 2')

print timeit(stmt='[func(x) for x in range(3) for func in (f, g)]',
             setup='gc.enable(); f = lambda x: x + 2; g = lambda x: x ** 2')


print timeit(stmt='list(chain.from_iterable((f(x), g(x)) for x in xrange(10**6)))',
             setup='gc.enable(); from itertools import chain; f = lambda x: x + 2; g = lambda x: x ** 2',
             number=20)

print timeit(stmt='list(chain.from_iterable(fg(x) for x in xrange(10**6)))',
             setup='gc.enable(); from itertools import chain; from __main__ import fg; f = lambda x: x + 2; g = lambda x: x ** 2',
             number=20)

print timeit(stmt='[func(x) for x in xrange(10**6) for func in (f, g)]',
             setup='gc.enable(); f = lambda x: x + 2; g = lambda x: x ** 2',
             number=20)
```

> 2.69210777094
>
> 3.13900787874
>
> 1.62461071932
>
> 25.5944058287
>
> 29.2623711793
>
> 25.7211849286

Comment: This code creates unnecessary tuples `(f(x), g(x))`. Could be better written as: `def fg(x): yield x + 2; yield x ** 2; list(chain.from_iterable(fg(x) for x in range(3)))`.

Comment: You could even generalize it with `chain.from_iterable((func(x) for func in funcs) for x in range(n)))`. Which would incidentally eliminate khachik's complaint. (Though in a sense, mine and his are essentially the same in terms of process. We simply define the inner generator differently.)

Comment: This is better than my `sum(..., [])` answer because it does not require recreating the list on every + (thus has O(N) performance rather than O(N^2) performance). I'll still use `sum(..., [])` when I want a quick one-liner or I'm in a hurry, or when the number of terms being combined is bounded (e.g. <= 10).

Comment: @khachik I think this would be faster but I will time both methods now, tuples are generated very fast in python though.

Comment: @jamylak: Thank you. I'd also be quite curious to see the performance for `[]`.

Comment: @khachik Actually the way you have set it out removes the functions entirely. I'll edit it to use them

Comment: @jamylak: Think of it as `def fg(x): yield f(x); yield g(x);`

Comment: @JAB ye that's what I'm doing

Comment: @jamylak, tuples are generated fast and they have fast access, but for large inputs that will put burden to gc.

Comment: A third answer, which disappeared, looked like this:

`[y for x in range(n) for y in (f(x), g(x))]`
But this is probably slower. @jamylak You could test this too if you want.

Comment: Yielding creates générators. Small tuples can be faster than generators. Anyway I don't think it's such a big issue.

Comment: @jamylak: you also need timings for range(10**6), because that's when some methods break down.

Comment: @Hashmush List comp is a lot faster actually, involves less function calls. Ok I will try some other ranges

Comment: @ninjagecko seems you are correct, list comp becomes slower for huge lists and I think we can agree that the tuples are fast. I think this is due to the fact that pure python code is generally slower ie. `yield`.

Comment: @jamylak: I think you also may wish to re-enable garbage collection, which is turned off by default with timeit: http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit I was mostly thinking that the `sum(...)` approach I mentioned would become slower actually, was not expecting the list comprehension approach to do so. Perhaps this is because the way you wrote it as `... (f(x), g(x))` is not a constant while `... (f,g)` is? Unsure.

Comment: I think the takeaway is that performance does not matter between this method and double-list-comp (same order of magnitude) unless this is a critical section of code.

Comment: @ninjagecko changing `... (f(x), g(x))` doesn't make a difference however tunring on garbage collection makes the list comp and chain perform at almost the exact same speed, I'll post those results now. I'll just change those to the default results.

Comment: I'm using this to unpack multiple tuples that are contained in a list like this:   

   `print '{} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(*list( chain.from_iterable( [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)] )))`

Comment: @nmz787 In that case I would probably use `' '.join(map(str, chain.from_iterable( [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)] )))`  So you don't have to type `{}` multiple times

Comment: @jamylak That would work in some cases, but unpacking the list into the format() command ensures I have the required number of unpacked values.

Answer (score 189):

Double list comprehension:

```
[f(x) for x in range(5) for f in (f1,f2)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> f1 = lambda x: x
>>> f2 = lambda x: 10*x

>>> [f(x) for x in range(5) for f in (f1,f2)]
[0, 0, 1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30, 4, 40]
```

Comment: This is nice because it shows that double list comps aren't so scary: they're simply nested for loops written *just like for loops*.  `for x in range(5): for f in (f1, f2): newlist.append(f(x))`.  I used to find them a little confusing because I kept trying to invert the order.

Comment: @DSM i think, it will be confusing forever.)

Answer (score 19):

```
sum( ([f(x),g(x)] for x in range(n)), [] )
```

This is equivalent to `[f(1),g(1)] + [f(2),g(2)] + [f(3),g(3)] + ...`

You can also think of it as:

```
def flatten(list):
    ...

flatten( [f(x),g(x)] for x in ... )
```

note: The right way is to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` or the double list comprehension. (It does not require recreating the list on every +, thus has O(N) performance rather than O(N^2) performance.) I'll still use `sum(..., [])` when I want a quick one-liner or I'm in a hurry, or when the number of terms being combined is bounded (e.g. <= 10). That is why I still mention it here, with this caveat. You can also use tuples: `((f(x),g(x)) for ...), ()` (or per khachik's comment, having a generator fg(x) which yields a two-tuple).

Comment: @ArashThr: it is doing `[f(1),g(1)] + [f(2),g(2)] + [f(3),g(3)] + ...`

Comment: Can you explain what is it doing exactly ?

Comment: Note: This has O(N^2) runtime so it could be slow on huge lists.

Comment: @jamylak: yes, I mentioned this on your answer in the comments as well. =)

Comment: I consider abusing `sum()` in this way an antipattern, and I don't see any justification to use it in whatever circumstances.  The code in your other answer is less typing, so even the excuse "when I want a quick one-liner or I'm in a hurry" does not really cut it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: well I'd say the issue is that python uses `+` for list concatenation, which unfortunately is not commutative like mathematical uses of `+`. As long as python uses this `+` though, I don't consider it an antipattern in the context of the language, though I would consider poor design choice on the part of the language. Well, it is ugly in that you have to specify `[]` for the case where you have an empty list.

Comment: @ninjagecko: There is nothing wrong about Python using `+` for concatenation. It's also used for `tuple` and string concatenation. Using `sum()` for strings has been explicitly disabled, but it unfortunately still works for lists and tuples. Addition and concatenation are different things anyway – the `operator` module has `add()` for the former and `concat()` for the latter.  The function `sum()` is definitely meant to compute sums, and using it for concatenation is an abuse.

Comment: Together with its catastrophic performance and the fact that the right solution is even more succinct, this makes using `sum()` for lists an antipattern in my book.

Answer (score 5):

I know OP is looking for a list comprehension solution, but I'd like to offer an alternative using `list.extend()`.

```
f = lambda x: x
g = lambda x: 10*x

result = []
extend = result.extend
for x in range(5):
    extend((f(x),g(x)))
```

which is marginally faster than using double list comprehension.

```py
nums = range(100000)

def double_comprehension():
    return [func(x) for x in nums for func in (f,g)]

def list_extend():
    result = []
    extend = result.extend
    for x in nums:
        extend((f(x),g(x)))
    return result

%timeit -n100 double_comprehension()
23.4 ms ± 67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n100 list_extend()
20.5 ms ± 213 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Python version: 3.8.0

Comment: This is a good example in which list comprehension is not always better than simply expanding the list.

Answer (score 2):

This lambda function zips two lists into a single one:

```
zipped = lambda L1, L2: [L[i] 
                         for i in range(min(len(L1), len(L2))) 
                         for L in (L1, L2)]
```

Example:

```
>>> f = [x for x in range(5)]
>>> g = [x*10 for x in range(5)]
>>> zipped(f, g)
[0, 0, 1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30, 4, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```py
from functools import reduce

f    = lambda x: f"f({x})" ## Just for example
g    = lambda x: f"g({x})"
data = [1, 2, 3]

reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + [f(x), g(x)], data, [])
# => ['f(1)', 'g(1)', 'f(2)', 'g(2)', 'f(3)', 'g(3)']
```

This is a functional way of approaching the problem. A list comprehension is essentially another way of `map`ing over data, but in cases such as this one where the mapping isn't one to one between the input and the output, `reduce` allows some wiggle room with how the output can be generated.

In general, any `for` implementation of the form:

```py
result = []
for n in some_data:
  result += some_operation()
  ## etc.
```

<sub>(I.e. for loops intended to produce a side effect on a list or similar data structure, the [accumulator pattern](https://gist.github.com/the-vampiire/923bd634fbabd5b4a0fc25aeb48bd37d#the-accumulator-pattern))</sub>

Can be refactored into a declarative `map/reduce/filter` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When reasonably possible, you should prefer using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) over using two `for` clauses in a list comprehension. Some style guides, such as the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#274-decision) forbid using multiple `for` clauses in a list comprehension. While you may be using a style guide that doesn't explicitly forbid this practice, you can still make the comprehension more concise by doing something like the following:

```py
from itertools import product

result = [y(x) for y, x in product(range(n), (f, g))]
```

Answer (score -2):

Goodness, grief! Why all these lambdas, flattens, zips and sums? Isn't this the simplest and most readable:

```
>>> [v
...  for x in range(5)
...      for v in (2 * x,
...                2 * x + 1)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

(Replace the last two expressions with `f(x)` and `g(x)`, or whatever.)