# Adding two items at a time in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

> I want to add two items at a time to a list comprehension. One item is constant. How can this be achieved using only one for loop inside of a list comprehension, and no additional functions. Answers that do not use any import will be favored.

Take a look at at the following:

```
>>> mystring = 'ABCELKJSDLHFWEHSJDHFKHIUEHFSDF'
>>> sum([['^', char] for char in mystring.lower()], [])
['^', 'a', '^', 'b', '^', 'c', '^', 'e', '^', 'l', '^', 'k', '^', 'j', '^', 's', '^', 'd', '^', 'l', '^', 'h', '^', 'f', '^', 'w', '^', 'e', '^', 'h', '^', 's', '^', 'j', '^', 'd', '^', 'h', '^', 'f', '^', 'k', '^', 'h', '^', 'i', '^', 'u', '^', 'e', '^', 'h', '^', 'f', '^', 's', '^', 'd', '^', 'f']
```

I am trying to make a list with the character `^` prepended before each letter in lower case. In this example, you need to use `sum` to flatten the list. However, my question is, if it is possible to make a flat list in the first place. The output above is the desired output.

As in, append something *constantly* before a variable that changes with each iteration of the `for` loop. One cannot use two `for` loops here, as that would be too simple, for example:

```
mystring = 'ABCELKJSDLHFWEHSJDHFKHIUEHFSDF'
print [item for x in mystring.lower() for item in ['^', x]]
```

If one does something like this:

```
>>> mystring = 'ABCELKJSDLHFWEHSJDHFKHIUEHFSDF'
>>> [['^', x] for x in mystring]
['^', 'a', '^', 'b', '^', 'c', '^', 'e', '^', 'l', '^', 'k', '^', 'j', '^', 's', '^', 'd', '^', 'l', '^', 'h', '^', 'f', '^', 'w', '^', 'e', '^', 'h', '^', 's', '^', 'j', '^', 'd', '^', 'h', '^', 'f', '^', 'k', '^', 'h', '^', 'i', '^', 'u', '^', 'e', '^', 'h', '^', 'f', '^', 's', '^', 'd', '^', 'f']
```

You get lists within lists. Thus, is there a way that you can append two items at a time in a list comprehension without have to use an addition for loop or an additional function like `sum`? I ask this, because its something quite simple, yet I can't find a way to do it. If one tries to do the following:

```
>>> ['^', x for x in mystring.lower()]
  File "<console>", line 1
    ['^', x for x in mystring.lower()]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The attempt gives a `SyntaxError`. So, is what I'm asking impossible to do in Python? Using `()` gives me a list of tuples.

I've also *tried* using the `splat`/`unpacking` operator:

```
>>> [*['^', x] for x in mystring.lower()]
  File "<console>", line 1
    [*['^', x] for x in mystring.lower()]
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But as above, this too is a syntax error. Sorry for this late edit, but I *have* tried the following:

```
import itertools
mystring = "HELLOWORLD"
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(('^', x) for x in mystring.lower())))
```

But the above still required an import.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want `^` as separate list element, before each character, or just appended to the character.

Comment: Under the first code sample, the the output is given. I think its fairly clear.

Comment: Same question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868964/python-list-comprehension-returning-two-or-more-items-for-each-item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
print list( '^'.join(mystring.lower()) )
```

which gives:

```
['a', '^', 'b', '^', 'c', '^', ...]
```

So this would give the desired output:

```
l = list( '^'.join(mystring.lower()) )
l.insert(0, '^')
print l
```

And another way:

```
print [ y for x in zip(['^'] * len(mystring), mystring.lower()) for y in x ]
```

which gives:

```
['^', 'a', '^', 'b', '^', 'c', ...
```

Comment: This _is_ an interesting answer, but `^` has to come before the first letter.

Comment: The `insert` does what you expect

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, added a pure comprehension solution

Comment: @perreal Uses 2 `for` loops. And this is clearer `[item for x in mystring.lower() for item in ['^', x]]`

Comment: if `^` has to come before the first letter, `list('^'+'^'.join(mystring.lower()))` works and can be equivalently written `[x for x in '^' + '^'.join(mystring.lower())]`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, this is equivalent to that nested list comprehension version but slightly efficient(for large lists):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> mystring = 'ABCELKJSDLHFWEHSJDHFKHIUEHFSDF'
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([['^', x] for x in mystring]))
['^', 'A', '^', 'B', '^', 'C', '^', 'E', '^', 'L', '^', 'K', '^', 'J', '^', 'S', '^', 'D', '^', 'L', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'W', '^', 'E', '^', 'H', '^', 'S', '^', 'J', '^', 'D', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'K', '^', 'H', '^', 'I', '^', 'U', '^', 'E', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'S', '^', 'D', '^', 'F']
```

In Python 3.3+ you can also use [`yield from`](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) in a generator function:

```
>>> mystring = 'ABCELKJSDLHFWEHSJDHFKHIUEHFSDF'
>>> def solve(strs):
...     for x in strs:
...         yield from ['^', x]
...         
>>> list(solve(mystring))
['^', 'A', '^', 'B', '^', 'C', '^', 'E', '^', 'L', '^', 'K', '^', 'J', '^', 'S', '^', 'D', '^', 'L', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'W', '^', 'E', '^', 'H', '^', 'S', '^', 'J', '^', 'D', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'K', '^', 'H', '^', 'I', '^', 'U', '^', 'E', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'S', '^', 'D', '^', 'F']
```

Comment: Is it possible without `itertools`, because I've tried this as well.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac `sum()` is highly inefficient for this([also not recommended for this purpose](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)), and `itertools.chain` will surely beat nested LC solution for larger lists.

Comment: I understand this, but is there no way to add one constant every time to a list comprehension? This feels like it _should_ be there. You are using imports, but its seems strange that something _this_ basic is not available. I understand that `sum` is inefficient, but that is besides the point, I just wanted to show what I've tried. Is there no way to use the `splat` operator in a creative way to get what I want?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac No splat operator will not work here.

Comment: So, I guess this can't be done without imports or nested for loops?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Yes, but you can use perreal's first solution if both `'^'` and `x` are both single length characters.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39558/discussion-between-games-brainiac-and-hcwhsa)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's using pydash, you can use [flatten_deep](https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pydash.arrays.flatten_deep). Basically, it recursively flattens your list down to one level so you can do a list comprehension of multiple lists.

```
>>> import pydash
>>> mystring = 'ABCELKJSDLHFWEHSJDHFKHIUEHFSDF' 
>>> pydash.flatten_deep([['^', x] for x in mystring])
['^', 'A', '^', 'B', '^', 'C', '^', 'E', '^', 'L', '^', 'K', '^', 'J', '^', 'S',           '^', 'D', '^', 'L', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'W', '^', 'E', '^', 'H', '^', 'S', '^', 'J', '^', 'D', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'K', '^', 'H', '^', 'I', '^', 'U', '^', 'E', '^', 'H', '^', 'F', '^', 'S', '^', 'D', '^', 'F']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this specific case...

```
>>> list('abcd'.replace('', '^')[ : -1])
['^', 'a', '^', 'b', '^', 'c', '^', 'd']
>>>
```