# How to add two element into a list using list comprehension in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to add two values in a list comprehension?

```
 [[x-0.5, x] if x != 0 and x % 30 == 0 else x for x in range(0, 60 + 1, 5)]
```

I tried the code above and it returns

```
 [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, [29.5, 30], 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, [59.5, 60]]
```

I've also tried

```
def f(x):
    return x-0.5, x
[f(x) if x !=0 and x % 30 == 0 else x for x in range(0, 60 + 1, 5)]
```

it returns

```
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, (29.5, 30), 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, (59.5, 60)]
```

How do I get rid of the bracket?

Edit:

This is what I am expecting

```
 [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 29.5, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 59.5, 60]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide expected input and output?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868964

Comment: Do you want that `60` at the end of the list?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I would like `x-0.5` and `x` in the list when `x % 30 == 0` , in this case I would like 29.5 and 30 along with 59.5 and 60 to be in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than one for-loop in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[y for x in range(0, 60 + 1, 5) 
   for y in ([x-0.5, x] if x != 0 and x % 30 == 0 else [x])]
```

yields

```
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 29.5, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 59.5, 60]
```

and is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for x in range(0, 60 + 1, 5):
    for y in ([x-0.5, x] if x != 0 and x % 30 == 0 else [x]):
        result.append(y)
```

Comment: Apparently the OP didn't literally mean "add" -- they just updated the question.  (This would be correct otherwise)

Comment: wow, thanks, I never imagine you can do multiple loops in a list comprehension, although can you explain how is the solution different than  `[[x-0.5, x] if x !=0 and x % 30 == 0 else x for [x] in range(0, 60 + 1, 5)]` which returns an error?

Comment: Python parses that as `[conditional-expression for x in range(...)]`. The conditional expression at the front of a list comprehension is the value that populates the list returned by the list comprehension. So if `[x-0.5, x]` is the value returned by the conditional expression, then that is the list that ends up being a value in the list comprehension.

Comment: I'm assuming you did not mean `[... for [x] in range(...)]` since that would lead to a TypeError.