# Generate multiple values in each iteration of a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, iterator, list-comprehension

I'd like to generate a list, say, `[0, 0^2, 1, 1^2, ... 9, 9^2]` in python. However, `[(i,i**2) for i in range(10)]` returns a list of tuples and `[*(i,i**2) for i in range(10)]` doesn't work.

Is there any pythonic way to create such a list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python (List Comprehension): Returning two (or more) items for each item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868964/python-list-comprehension-returning-two-or-more-items-for-each-item)

Comment: [val for n in range(10) for val in (n, n**2)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another level of iteration in the list comprehension to get a flat list:

```
[i**exp for i in range(10) for exp in [1,2]]
# [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81]
```

---

Or you could use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable((i,i**2) for i in range(10)))
# [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81]
```

---

Though I'd consider `numpy` for such task:

```
(np.arange(10)**np.arange(1,3)[:,None]).ravel('F')

array([ 0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  4,  3,  9,  4, 16,  5, 25,  6, 36,  7, 49,  8,
   64,  9, 81], dtype=int32)
```