# Unpack tuples in list comprehension with a condition

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

I'd like to build one of these lists of tuples:

- `(a, 0), (-a, 0) (b, 0), (-b, 0)`
- `(0, a), (0, -a) (0, b), (0, -b)`

from scalars `a` and `b`.

based on a condition:

- `c = a > b`

This is my attempt:

```
a = 5
b = 2
c = a > b

# Try build two tuples per element, e.g. (5, 0), (-5, 0) (2, 0), (-2, 0)

# This syntax is illegal
#f2 = [(m,0), (-m,0) if c else (0,m), (-0,-m) for m in (a,b)]

# This syntax works but creates tuples of tuples
f2 = [tuple(((m,0), (-m,0))) if c else tuple(((0,m), (-0,-m))) for m in (a,b)]
print(*f2) # ((5, 0), (-5, 0)) ((2, 0), (-2, 0))

# This syntax is illegal
#f3 = [*tuple(((m,0), (-m,0))) if c else *tuple(((0,m), (-0,-m))) for m in (a,b)]
#print(*f3)
```

`f2` builds a list of two tuples of two tuples: `((5, 0), (-5, 0)) ((2, 0), (-2, 0))`.
Using `*` operator in `f3` to unpack the outer tuples triggers a syntax error.

What is the correct syntax?

---

Also I don't understand why f2 is `((5, 0), (-5, 0)) ((2, 0), (-2, 0))`, where the outer tuples are not separated by a `,`?

Comment: I'd not use loop at all. `[(a, 0), (-a, 0), (b, 0), (-b, 0)] if c else [(0, a), (0, -a), (0, b), (0, -b)]`

Comment: Why do you need to call `tuple()` when you could just use the tuple literal syntax?

Comment: `f2 = [((m,0), (-m,0)) if c else ((0,m), (-0,-m)) for m in (a,b)]` isn't, though. You shouldn't need to reach for `tuple()` here but @OlvinRoght is probably correct with their suggestion, I'm just digging into an aside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with lambda functions.

```
x1 = lambda x : (x,0)
y1 = lambda x : (-x,0)
x2 = lambda x : (0,x)
y2 = lambda x : (-0,-x)
f2 = [f1(m) if c else f2(m) for m in (a,b) for f1,f2 in zip((x1,y1),(x2,y2))]
```

Output:
`[(5, 0), (-5, 0), (2, 0), (-2, 0)]`
A little bit over-engineered but makes sense.

*EDIT*
Also you can use chain from itertools to put 2 items in a single list comprehension.

```
from itertools import chain
f2 = list(
    chain.from_iterable(
        ((m,0), (-m,0)) if c else ((0,m), (-0,-m)) for m in (a,b)
    ))
```

[SEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868964/list-comprehension-returning-two-or-more-items-for-each-item)

Comment: @mins yeah I thought about it and came up with the chain. For more info check out the (answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868996/9354135]

Comment: `chain.from_iterable()` is functional way to implement nested loop. Nested list comprehension from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73762206/10824407#comment130250075_73762206) comment do exactly the same.

Comment: @mins, actually no "tricks" needed `[(j, 0) if c else (0, j) for i in (a, b) for j in (i, -i)]`

Answer (score 2):

In this case you don't really need any loops, you can use condition:

```py
a = 5
b = 2
c = a > b

f2 = [(a, 0), (-a, 0), (b, 0), (-b, 0)] if c else [(0, a), (0, -a), (0, b), (0, -b)]
```

If *(for some reason)* you want to solve it with list comprehension, you can use next:

```py
f2 = [(j, 0) if c else (0, j) for i in (a, b) for j in (i, -i)]
```